# Php select Box from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need your help in my web interface i have a select box that return data fo mysql database so i want when i select something from my select box i need it to appear in textarea this is my code :

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynamic Dependent Dropdown with jQuery</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').change(function(){
        var country_id = $('#country').val();
        if(country_id != 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'getvalue.php',
                data:{id:country_id},
                cache:false,
                success: function(returndata){
                    $('#city').html(returndata);
                }
            });
        }
    })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Dynamic Dependent Dropdown with jQuery</h1>
    <p><a href="http://coffeecupweb.com/">http://coffeecupweb.com/</a></p>
    <form>
    <div class="inputbox">
        <select id="country" class="selectbox">
            <option value="0">Please Select a country</option>
            <?php $sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `countries`'); ?>
            <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="inputbox">
        <select id="city" class="selectbox">
            <option value="0">Please select a city</option>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<select name="test[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="and">and</option>
        <option value="or">or</option>
        <option value="==">==</option>
        <option value=">">></option>
        <option value="<"><</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<?php
        $test=$_POST['test'];
        if ($test){
         foreach ($test as $t){echo 'You selected ',$t,'<br />';}
        }
?>
Text: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40">
<?php
        $comment=$_POST['country'];
        if ($test){
         foreach ($test as $t){echo 'You selected ',$t,'<br />';}
        }
         $comment=$_POST['city'];
        if ($comment){
         foreach ($comment as $t1){echo 'You selected ',$t1,'<br />';}
        }

?></textarea> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

this code works well when i select my country with the city but it dosen't work in the textarea where i want each one i select something from one of select boxes appear in my select box .thankyou in advance

Comment: Your problem is about the `#city` that is not filled ?

Answer (score 1):

use a javascript event ..write a function that will take the select value and append it to the text area's existing data.

```
 onselect="saveDataToTextArea();"

  <script> 
  function saveDataToTextArea(){
   var selectedValue = $("#idOfSelectField").val();
    $("#idOfTextArea").val($("#idOfTextArea").val()+selectedValue );
   }  
  </script>
```

Comment: can you show me how to implemented in my script.. thankyou @Danyal Sandeelo

Comment: I can guide you :) won't fix your code :) try it yourself, you will learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `name` attributes to the `<select>` elements, so that `$_POST['country']` and `$_POST['city']` will be filled in.

```
<select id="country" name="country" class="selectbox">

<select id="city" name="city" class="selectbox">
```